How to convert a ECPrivateKey to a PEM-encoded OpenSSH format?
Given this randomly generated ECDSA private key:
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAaAAAABNlY2RzYS
1zaGEyLW5pc3RwMjU2AAAACG5pc3RwMjU2AAAAQQR1n1SFvy7Di392GmMy8JsWEjbffTCu
nGKwZrIgq/yIy1C33ud4bxN3W4vbXCtZfyPeVbWNpW1eXSZ/3uWmcJ3SAAAAmCxLaSMsS2
kjAAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBHWfVIW/LsOLf3Ya
YzLwmxYSNt99MK6cYrBmsiCr/IjLULfe53hvE3dbi9tcK1l/I95VtY2lbV5dJn/e5aZwnd
IAAAAgUgu0f1JX6BTUL3UU3Xq3C8erF/W2cIgzuCHciLp55HYAAAAA
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

I am using this code to parse it into a PrivateKey:
public PrivateKey readPrivateKeyAsOpenSsh(Reader reader) throws IOException
{
    try (PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(reader))
    {
        PemObject pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
        byte[] content = pemObject.getContent();
        AsymmetricKeyParameter keyParameter = OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil.parsePrivateKeyBlob(content);
        if (!(keyParameter instanceof ECPrivateKeyParameters ecPrivateKeyParameters))
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported format: " + pemObject.getType());
        BigInteger d = ecPrivateKeyParameters.getD();
            ECNamedCurveSpec ecNamedCurveSpec = getEcNamedCurveSpec(ecPrivateKeyParameters);
        ECPrivateKeySpec ecPrivateKeySpec = new ECPrivateKeySpec(d, ecNamedCurveSpec);
            KeyFactory keyFactory;
        try
        {
            keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
            return keyFactory.generatePrivate(ecPrivateKeySpec);
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e)
        {
            // Deployment-time decision
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the name of a key's algorithm.
 *
 * @param keyParameter a key's parameters
 * @return the name of the key's algorithm
 * @throws IOException if the algorithm is unsupported
 */
private static String getAlgorithm(AsymmetricKeyParameter keyParameter) throws IOException
{
    return switch (keyParameter)
    {
        case RSAKeyParameters _ -> "RSA";
        case DSAPublicKeyParameters _ -> "DSA";
        case ECPublicKeyParameters _ -> "EC";
        default -> throw new IOException("Unsupported key parameter: " +
            keyParameter.getClass().getName());
    };
}

/**
 * @param keyParameters the private key's parameters
 * @return the set of domain parameters used with elliptic curve cryptography (ECC)
 * @throws IOException if the elliptical curve used is unknown
 */
private ECNamedCurveSpec getEcNamedCurveSpec(ECPrivateKeyParameters keyParameters) throws IOException
{
    ECDomainParameters domainParameters = keyParameters.getParameters();
    X9ECParameters x9ECParameters = getX9EcParameters(domainParameters);
    if (x9ECParameters == null)
        throw new IOException("Failed to convert domain parameters to X9ECParameters");

    EllipticCurve ellipticCurve = new EllipticCurve(
        new ECFieldFp(x9ECParameters.getCurve().getField().getCharacteristic()),
        x9ECParameters.getCurve().getA().toBigInteger(),
        x9ECParameters.getCurve().getB().toBigInteger());
    ECPoint g = x9ECParameters.getG();

    String curveName = getCurveName(domainParameters);
    if (curveName == null)
        throw new IOException("Failed to find the curve name");
    return new ECNamedCurveSpec(curveName,
        ellipticCurve,
        new java.security.spec.ECPoint(
            g.getAffineXCoord().toBigInteger(),
            g.getAffineYCoord().toBigInteger()),
        x9ECParameters.getN(),
        x9ECParameters.getH());
}

/**
 * Returns the X9ECParameters of the curve with the specified domain parameters.
 *
 * @param domainParameters domain parameters
 * @return null if no match is found
 */
private X9ECParameters getX9EcParameters(ECDomainParameters domainParameters)
{
    Entry<String, X9ECParameters> details = getCurveDetails(domainParameters);
    if (details == null)
        return null;
    return details.getValue();
}

/**
 * Returns the name of the curve with the specified domain parameters.
 *
 * @param domainParameters domain parameters
 * @return null if no match is found
 */
private String getCurveName(ECDomainParameters domainParameters)
{
    Entry<String, X9ECParameters> details = getCurveDetails(domainParameters);
    if (details == null)
        return null;
    return details.getKey();
}

/**
 * Returns the name and X9ECParameters of the curve with the specified domain parameters.
 *
 * @param domainParameters domain parameters
 * @return null if no match is found
 */
private Entry<String, X9ECParameters> getCurveDetails(ECDomainParameters domainParameters)
{
    for (Enumeration<?> e = ECNamedCurveTable.getNames(); e.hasMoreElements(); )
    {
        String name = (String) e.nextElement();
        X9ECParameters x9EcParams = ECNamedCurveTable.getByName(name);
        if (x9EcParams.getCurve().equals(domainParameters.getCurve()))
            return new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(name, x9EcParams);
    }
    return null;
}

This seems to work, but I can't figure out how to convert it bck to a PEM-encoded OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY. Here is the code that isn't working:
/**
 * Writes a {@code PrivateKey} as a PEM-encoded OpenSSH format stream.
 *
 * @param privateKey the key
 * @param writer     the stream to write into
 * @throws NullPointerException if any of the arguments are null
 * @throws IOException          if an error occurs while writing into the stream
 */
public void writePrivateKeyAsOpenSsh(ECPrivateKey privateKey, Writer writer) throws IOException
{
    AsymmetricKeyParameter param = getAsymmetricKeyParameter(privateKey);
        try (JcaPEMWriter pemWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(writer))
    {
        byte[] encodedPrivateKey = OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil.encodePrivateKey(param);
        PemObject pemObject = new PemObject("OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY", encodedPrivateKey);
        pemWriter.writeObject(pemObject);
        pemWriter.flush();
    }
}

It returns this output:
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBaAIBAQQgUgu0f1JX6BTUL3UU3Xq3C8erF/W2cIgzuCHciLp55HaggfowgfcC
AQEwLAYHKoZIzj0BAQIhAP////8AAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////////
MFsEIP////8AAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA///////////////8BCBaxjXYqjqT57Pr
vVV2mIa8ZR0GsMxTsPY7zjw+J9JgSwMVAMSdNgiG5wSTamZ44ROdJreBn36QBEEE
axfR8uEsQkf4vOblY6RA8ncDfYEt6zOg9KE5RdiYwpZP40Li/hp/m47n60p8D54W
K84zV2sxXs7LtkBoN79R9QIhAP////8AAAAA//////////+85vqtpxeehPO5ysL8
YyVRAgEBoUQDQgAEdZ9Uhb8uw4t/dhpjMvCbFhI2330wrpxisGayIKv8iMtQt97n
eG8Td1uL21wrWX8j3lW1jaVtXl0mf97lpnCd0g==
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

which doesn't seem to be a valid key. I search discussion forums and the BouncyCastle testcases to no avail.
Any ideas?

If there is an easier way to parse the original input, please let me know.
Please don't suggest the use of libraries other than JCA or BouncyCastle unless there is no other way.

Thank you in advance.

Why do you think that "doesn't seem to be a valid key"?

OpenSSH used formerly the SEC1 format for private EC keys. The key generated by you at the end with BC has the SEC1 format (however, the header and footer are wrong, correct is: -----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----/-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----). OpenSSH now has its own format for private keys. The OpenSSH key posted at the beginning has this format. I suspect that BC does not support this new format when converting to an OpenSSH key. An alternative is to implement the conversion yourself. Here is a description of the new format.

I got the following working using the MINA sshd library (https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd):
/**
 * Writes a {@code KeyPair} as a PEM-encoded OpenSSH format stream.
 *
 * @param keys a key pair
 * @param out  the stream to write into
 * @throws NullPointerException     if any of the arguments are null
 * @throws IOException              if an error occurs while reading the stream
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the key pair is unsupported or invalid
 */
public void writeKeyPairAsOpenSsh(Collection<KeyPair> keys, OutputStream out)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{
    OpenSSHKeyPairResourceWriter openSshWriter = OpenSSHKeyPairResourceWriter.INSTANCE;
    for (KeyPair key : keys)
        openSshWriter.writePrivateKey(key, null, null, out);
}

Short and to the point.

OpenSSH originally used the SEC1 format for ECDSA private keys and introduced a new custom format in 2014. This new format is sparsely documented, e.g. here, more details can be found in The OpenSSH private key binary format and The OpenSSH Private Key Format.
BouncyCastle is capable of importing the new format with OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil.parsePrivateKeyBlob(), but the export does not seem to be supported, in particular OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil.encodePrivateKey() produces a key in SEC1 format.
The following implementation exports an ECPrivateKey key in OpenSSH format, where the algorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 and ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 are supported, here:
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Random;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECPrivateKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.ECUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Arrays;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

...

class Converter {
    
    // supports ECDSA for nistp256, nistp384 and nistp521
    public String convertToOpenSshPrivateKey(ECPrivateKey ecPrivateKey) throws Exception {
        
        // get keytpe, pub0
        byte[] keyType = getKeyType(ecPrivateKey).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] pub0 = Arrays.copyOfRange(keyType, keyType.length - 8, keyType.length);
        
        // get raw private key and calculate raw public key
        byte[] rawPrivateKey =  ecPrivateKey.getS().toByteArray(); // signed byte array
        ECPoint g = ((ECPrivateKeyParameters)ECUtil.generatePrivateKeyParameter(ecPrivateKey)).getParameters().getG();
        byte[] uncompressedPublicKey = g.multiply(ecPrivateKey.getS()).getEncoded(false);
        
        // public data
        int publicDataSize = 
                4 + keyType.length +                // 32-bit length, keytype
                4 + pub0.length +                   // 32-bit length, pub0
                4 + uncompressedPublicKey.length;   // 32-bit length, pub1
        ByteBuffer publicData = ByteBuffer.allocate(publicDataSize);  
        publicData.putInt(keyType.length); publicData.put(keyType);
        publicData.putInt(pub0.length); publicData.put(pub0);
        publicData.putInt(uncompressedPublicKey.length); publicData.put(uncompressedPublicKey);
        
        // private data
        int privateDataSizeUnpadded =               
                8 +                                 // 64-bit dummy checksum
                publicData.position() +             // public key parts 
                4 + rawPrivateKey.length +          // 64-bit dummy checksum
                4;                                  // 32-bit length, comment
        int paddingSize = (8 - privateDataSizeUnpadded % 8) % 8;
        int privateDataSize =               
                privateDataSizeUnpadded +           // private data, unpadded    
                paddingSize;                        // padding
        ByteBuffer privateData = ByteBuffer.allocate(privateDataSize);
        int chcksm = new Random().nextInt();
        privateData.putInt(chcksm); privateData.putInt(chcksm);
        privateData.put(publicData.array(), 0, publicData.position());
        privateData.putInt(rawPrivateKey.length); privateData.put(rawPrivateKey);
        privateData.putInt(0);
        byte[] paddingBlock = new byte[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; // no cipher: blocksize: 8 
        byte[] padding = Arrays.copyOfRange(paddingBlock, 0, paddingSize);
        privateData.put(padding);
        
        // all data
        byte[] prefix = "openssh-key-v1\0".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] none = "none".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int allDataSize = 
                prefix.length +                     // "openssh-key-v1"0x00
                4 + none.length +                   // 32-bit length, "none" 
                4 + none.length +                   // 32-bit length, "none"
                4 +                                 // 32-bit length, nil
                4 +                                 // 32-bit 0x01
                4 + publicData.position() +         // 32-bit length, public key parts
                4 + privateData.position();         // 32-bit length, private key parts
        ByteBuffer allData = ByteBuffer.allocate(allDataSize);
        allData.put(prefix); 
        allData.putInt(none.length); allData.put(none); 
        allData.putInt(none.length); allData.put(none); 
        allData.putInt(0); 
        allData.putInt(1);
        allData.putInt(publicData.position()); allData.put(publicData.array(), 0, publicData.position());
        allData.putInt(privateData.position()); allData.put(privateData.array(), 0, privateData.position());

        return format(allData.array(), 70, "\r\n");
    }
    
    private static String getKeyType(ECPrivateKey ecPrivateKey) {
        PrivateKeyInfo pki = PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(ASN1Sequence.getInstance(ecPrivateKey.getEncoded()));
        ASN1ObjectIdentifier oid = ASN1ObjectIdentifier.getInstance(pki.getPrivateKeyAlgorithm().getParameters());
        if (oid.equals(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.10045.3.1.7"))) {
            return "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256";
        } else if (oid.equals(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.3.132.0.34"))) {
            return "ecdsa-sha2-nistp384";
        } else if (oid.equals(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.3.132.0.35"))) {
            return "ecdsa-sha2-nistp521";
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("key type not defined");
        }
    }
    
    private static String format(byte[] data, int length, String sep) {
        String dataB64 = Base64.toBase64String(data);
        String[] dataB64Splitted = dataB64.split("(?<=\\G.{" + length + "})");
        String body = String.join(sep, dataB64Splitted);
        return String.format("%s%s%s%s%s", "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----", sep, body, sep, "-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----");
    }
    
    public PrivateKey readPrivateKeyAsOpenSsh(Reader reader) throws IOException
    {
        ...
}


The following test imports the OpenSSH key and exports it again. Thereby the original key is created (apart from the random checksum fields):
String key = "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n"
           + "b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAaAAAABNlY2RzYS\r\n"
           + "1zaGEyLW5pc3RwMjU2AAAACG5pc3RwMjU2AAAAQQR1n1SFvy7Di392GmMy8JsWEjbffTCu\r\n"
           + "nGKwZrIgq/yIy1C33ud4bxN3W4vbXCtZfyPeVbWNpW1eXSZ/3uWmcJ3SAAAAmCxLaSMsS2\r\n"
           + "kjAAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBHWfVIW/LsOLf3Ya\r\n"
           + "YzLwmxYSNt99MK6cYrBmsiCr/IjLULfe53hvE3dbi9tcK1l/I95VtY2lbV5dJn/e5aZwnd\r\n"
           + "IAAAAgUgu0f1JX6BTUL3UU3Xq3C8erF/W2cIgzuCHciLp55HYAAAAA\r\n"
           + "-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----";

Converter converter = new Converter();
ECPrivateKey ecPrivateKey = (ECPrivateKey)converter.readPrivateKeyAsOpenSsh(new StringReader(key));     
String opensshKey = converter.convertToOpenSshPrivateKey(ecPrivateKey);
System.out.println(opensshKey); // outputs the above OpenSSH key


Thank you for the helpful background information. I tried using your code but ran across this exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLSequence  at org.bouncycastle.provider/org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier.getInstance(Unknown Source)  at app.licensed.common/app.licensed.common.util.SshKeys.getKeyType(SshKeys.java:351) . For what it's worth, I ended up finding a working solution using Apache MINA sshd. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/79267020/14731

@Gili - In my environment and here on jdoodle https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/1y78 it works. Possibly the problem is reproducible with a different key. I have done some testing, but of course not in the depth of an established library, so MINA is certainly the more reliable option.
